# cache webpage using java proxy server

Tags: java, proxy, server, html

I'm trying to study client/server using java. Need you help guys. Thanks in advance.

I built a proxy server that connects to the browser, what I would like to do is when it connects to the browser it will cache or download the webpage that the browser visited. Is it possible? Any tips or materials you can suggest? if possible, a sample code would be perfect because I really don't have any idea on how to do it.

Here is my code for my proxy server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test extends Thread {

Socket connectedClient = null;  
BufferedReader inFromClient = null; // request from the client (browser)
DataOutputStream outToClient = null; // response to client (browser)


public test(Socket client) {
    connectedClient = client;
}           

public void run() {

    try {

        System.out.println( "The Client "+
        connectedClient.getInetAddress() + ":" + connectedClient.getPort() + " is connected");

        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connectedClient.getInputStream()));                  
        outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());

        String requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
        String headerLine = requestString;

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(headerLine);
        String httpMethod = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String httpQueryString = tokenizer.nextToken();

        StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        responseBuffer.append("The HTTP Client request is ....<BR>");

        System.out.println("The HTTP request string is ....");
        while (inFromClient.ready())
       {
            // Read the HTTP complete HTTP Query
            responseBuffer.append(requestString + "<BR>");
            System.out.println(requestString);
            requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
        }        

        if (httpMethod.equals("GET")) {

          if (httpQueryString.equals("/")) {
            // The default home page
            httprequest(200, responseBuffer.toString());                            
          } else {
            //filename : request from the client 
            String fileName = httpQueryString;

            fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName);
            System.out.println("Request:" + fileName);
            httprequest(200,fileName);                              
          }

        } 
        else httprequest(404, "<b>The Requested resource not found ....</b>");              
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
public void httprequest(int statusCode,String location) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String line = null;

    URL serverAddress = null;
    String statusLine = null;
    String serverdetails = "Server: Java ProxyServer";
    String contentTypeLine = "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

    if (statusCode == 200)
    {
                statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\r\n";
        try {
             serverAddress = new URL(location);

              connection = null;


              connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
              connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
              connection.setDoOutput(true);

              connection.connect();

              //read the result from the server
            InputStream rd = connection.getInputStream();
            outToClient.writeBytes(statusLine);
            outToClient.writeBytes(serverdetails);
            outToClient.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);
            outToClient.writeBytes("\r\n");


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] ;
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = rd.read(buffer)) != -1 ){
            outToClient.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    else{
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" + "\r\n"; 
        outToClient.writeBytes(statusLine);
        outToClient.writeBytes(serverdetails);
        outToClient.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);

     }

  outToClient.close();
}


public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

    //System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","172.16.1.254") ;
   // System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128") ;

    ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (8080, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));         
    System.out.println ("Proxy Server Waiting for client on port 8080");

    while(true) {                                   
            Socket connected = Server.accept();
            (new test(connected)).start();
    }      
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want monitor HTTP trafic, Take a reference from this, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm even I built by my own by taking references from this kinda resources. But SSL communication you cannot do monitoring.

Comment: Thanks! I will take time to read it. But do you have any idea on how to cache a webpage using a proxyserver?

Comment: I don't have enough idea about cache, but for Proxy server. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks anyways Pasupathi! :) Thank you for the material, trying to update my proxy server. hehe